# Iam getting PlatformException Error aka dart-vm-initializer.cc(41) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

Iam Getting PlatformException Error which returns null value

`PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)` or `[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)`

My Main.dart file:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final Future<FirebaseApp> _fApp = Firebase.initializeApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Elite App")),
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: _fApp,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print("aaa");
              print(snapshot.error);
              return Text("Yes Error");
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text("Success");
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

My android/app level build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
android {
    namespace "com.hackelite.hack_elite"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.hackelite.hack_elite"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

My Android level build file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried flutter clean, also b deleting .gradle file
and also including

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    // Replace with actual values
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "XXX",
      appId: "XXX",
      messagingSenderId: "XXX",
      projectId: "XXX",
    ),
  );
```

and also

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

I tried almost everything I can and Nothing works for me...